# Is is possible to set test case results from an ADO deployment pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vstest

I have a test project.  The project has tests that are associated with test cases in our backlog.  Our release pipeline builds and runs the tests as part of our deployment using the VSTest task.  The tests run and complete successfully.  I can view the results of the run in Azure test plan, however the associated test cases do not get marked as pass/fail.

Should we be able to do this from the pipeline?  Is there something in particular that I might be missing?

Tried to run a test project using VSTest from a release pipeline.

Expected test cases associated with automated the tests to be marked as pass/fail

Comment: Hi there, Have you got a chance to go through the answer below? May I know if it works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you can use `VSTEST` with the test selection of `Test plan` option. Kindly take my sample below for a reference.

1. I have an **active** test case (#838) under `Test Suite - Test in release pipeline` (#839) in the test plan of `DotNetTest` (#836) which is [associated with test assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops) `AzureWebAppDotNetCoreTests.dll`;
   [image]
2. In one of the stages of my release pipeline, I use the `VSTest` task and select the expected Test plan\Test Suite;
   [image]
3. During a new release, the pipeline will search the associated assembly from the `Search folder` and execute automated tests;
4. Running this test in release pipeline will then populate test runs and automatically update the result for the test case.
   [image]

Hope the suggestion could meet your expectations.

Comment: Thank for the answer.  This makes sense.  I'm investigating this now.  Do you simply updated your release pipeline at every release and select a new suite?

Comment: I got this working.  It appears that one of the things that prevented it from working correctly was the "Test Configuration" drop down mismatching what was configured in my Test Suite.